# Specific custom made SharePoint permissions to read only and save as a copy online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions, team-sites

I have a folder in SharePoint containing several files and folders. I want to provide my colleagues with view-only access to this folder.

However, I also want to enable them to use the 'Save As' feature to create copies of file in another folder within the same SharePoint location. Which permissions should I apply to achieve this?

The challenge I'm facing is that when I grant them only 'Read' permissions, they are unable to use the 'Save As' functionality, which is understandable.

[image: Save a Copy online]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Save as - Save a copy online** option is available only if you have **Edit** permissions on the files (default behavior in SharePoint).

---

**Workaround**:

If you want to allow users to create a copy of existing files in the SharePoint document library where they have only **Read** permissions, follow this steps:

1. Grant **Read** access to files in the SharePoint document library to the users - files they will be copying to another folder.
2. Grant **Contribute** or higher (Edit/Full Control) access to folders where users will create copies of file (within the same SharePoint location).
3. Go to SharePoint library > locate the files with **Read** access > select the file using check box and click **Copy to** from top command bar:

   [image]
4. Select another folder in the same SharePoint document library (with contribute or higher permissions) and click **Copy here** button to create a copy of the file:

   [image]
5. Now go to the folder where you just created the copy of file and you will see that the new file can be edited by the users.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ganesh!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped you.